# Python GUI QCore.Aplication error

Tags: user-interface, pyqt, pyqtgraph, qcoreapplication

I had tried various workarounds about this problem and tried to fix code according to other examples, but ultimately I had failed to make a workable code. While I do have idea of why it fails, I lack skill to create a workaround about this error. Could you please help me with making this code to work?

The problem:

Then I press ''Duomenų apdorojimas'' and proceed to press ''Pavaizduoti signalą'' I get error saying: QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running. I tried various workarounds about this and some legacy code is left inside my functions. I will tidy and optimize my code later, I just need to know how to work properly with GUI in order to avoid this problem. If needed I will send you entire program with txt files, but this part is essential and here problem arises.

```
import os
import os.path
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import sys
from functools import partial
import matplotlib.pyplot as p

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

def __init__(self):

    super(Window, self).__init__()
    self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
    self.setWindowTitle("")
    self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('pythonlogo.png'))

    openFile = QtGui.QAction("&Atverkite duomenų failą", self)
    openFile.setShortcut("Ctrl+Q")
    openFile.setStatusTip('Duomenų failas')
    openFile.triggered.connect(self.file_open)

    extractAction = QtGui.QAction("&Duomenys iš Arduino", self)
    extractAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+W")
    extractAction.setStatusTip('Prijunkite iš Arduino ateinančius duomenis')
    extractAction.triggered.connect(self.upload_usb)

    saveFile = QtGui.QAction("&Įšsaugoti failą", self)
    saveFile.setShortcut("Ctrl+E")
    saveFile.setStatusTip('Nurodykite failo direktoriją bei pavadinimą')
    saveFile.triggered.connect(self.file_save)

    quitFile = QtGui.QAction("&Išeiti", self)
    quitFile.setShortcut("Ctrl+R")
    quitFile.setStatusTip('Programa bus uždaryta')
    quitFile.triggered.connect(self.close_application)

    openEditor = QtGui.QAction("&Skaitytuvas", self)
    openEditor.setShortcut("Ctrl+T")
    openEditor.setStatusTip('Skaitytuvas visados įjungtas')
    openEditor.triggered.connect(self.editor)

    additionalData = QtGui.QAction("&Paciento duomenys", self)
    additionalData.setShortcut("Ctrl+A")
    additionalData.setStatusTip('Įveskite paciento amžiaus grupę')
    additionalData.triggered.connect(self.group)

    dataProcessing = QtGui.QAction("&Filtruoti signalą", self)
    dataProcessing.setShortcut("Ctrl+S")
    dataProcessing.setStatusTip('Bus atliekami signalo apdorojimo procesai')
    dataProcessing.triggered.connect(self.editor)

    showGraph = QtGui.QAction("&Pavaizduoti signalą", self)
    showGraph.setShortcut("Ctrl+D")
    showGraph.setStatusTip('Bus atvaizduotas šiuo metu turimas signalas')
    showGraph.triggered.connect(self.close_application)

    mainMenu = self.menuBar()

    fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('&Progamos funkcijos')
    fileMenu.addAction(openFile)
    fileMenu.addAction(extractAction)
    fileMenu.addAction(saveFile)
    fileMenu.addAction(quitFile)

    resultsMenu = mainMenu.addMenu("&Duomenų apdorojimas")
    resultsMenu.addAction(dataProcessing)
    resultsMenu.addAction(showGraph)

    editorMenu = mainMenu.addMenu("&Programos nustatymai")
    editorMenu.addAction(openEditor)
    editorMenu.addAction(additionalData)

    self.statusBar()
    self.home()

def openFile(self,n):
    print(n)

def home(self):
    self.show()

def close_application(self):
    graphics()
    sys.exit()

def run():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

Comment: What does `graphics()` do?

Comment: graphics()  is a function which opens a separate graph window. This is the point of the problem since here program crashes because I try to open second QCore.Application loop or something. Hmmm, if solution to the problem is not clear I guess I will just post whole code instead for you to compile.

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear. Somewhere your code calls `QApplication.exec_()` again (note the first call is in the `run` function). Presumably this happens in `graphics()`. Without knowing what `graphics` is, there isn't much help that can be provided except to encourage you to learn more about `QApplication` instances and refactor your application so you aren't trying to make 2 and start 2 event loops.

Comment: Thank you for your help and sorry for late response. Holidays really mess up my usual schedules for a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that I was trying to open semi-new program in graphics(). I found out how not to create GUI. Thank you for you help, but I have found out solution. For the next time I will post code in onedrive or something in order for people to get whole program with its supporting documents.